# Cantidad de elementos que soporta la cláusula IN en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Buenos días,
Tengo que hacer un reporte con casi 9000 documentos de identidad y necesito saber ¿Cuántos elementos soporta la cláusula IN en MongoDB?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según los cálculos de [este usuario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18495467/3045491)  en Stack Overlow en inglés:

> 1,525,198 elementos

Comment: Muchas gracias.